# Image cropping method doesnt show "submit"

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, crop

This seems to be working if the height of the browser is less..

Otherwise I can't click on the "submit" button after I crop the picture

Please help me what am I doing wrong.
Here's the code:

```js
$('#drop').on('click', function() {
  $('#fileUpload').trigger('click');
});

$('#fileUpload').on('change', function(e) {
  addImage(e.target);
});

$("#drop").on("dragover", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  $(this).addClass('dragging');
});

$("#drop").on("dragleave", function(e) {
  $(this).removeClass('dragging');
});

$("#drop").on("drop", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var data = e.dataTransfer || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
  addImage(data);
});

function addImage(data) {
  var file = data.files[0];
  if (file.type.indexOf('image') === -1) {
    alert('Sorry, the file you uploaded doesn\'t appear to be an image.');
    return false;
  }

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
      if (img.width < 200 || img.height < 200) {
        alert('Sorry, the image you uploaded doesn\'t appear to be large enough.');
        return false;
      }
      cropImage(img);
    }
    img.src = event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function cropImage(originalImage) {

  $(originalImage).attr('id', 'fullImage');
  $('#imageResize').html(originalImage);
  $('#sectionDragAndDrop').addClass('hidden');
  $('#sectionResize').removeClass('hidden');

  var newImage = new imageCrop('#fullImage', 200, 200);

  $('#crop').on('click', function() {
    var results = newImage.crop();
    $('#thumbnail').html(results.img);
    $('#sectionResize').addClass('hidden');
    $('#sectionThumbnail').removeClass('hidden');
  });

}




// Requires jQuery
var imageCrop = function(imageTarget, requiredWidth, requiredHeight) {
  // Variables
  var $doc = $(document),
    $cropMarker,
    $originalImage,
    origSrc = new Image(),
    imageTarget = $(imageTarget).get(0),
    imageScale,
    imageRatio,
    cropRatio,
    adjustedRequiredWidth,
    adjustedRequiredHeight,
    eventState = {},
    allowResize = true,
    keyboardMove = false,
    imageLoaded = new $.Deferred();

  origSrc.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

  function init() {
    origSrc.onload = function() {
      // Check to make sure the target image is large enough
      if (origSrc.width < requiredWidth || origSrc.height < requiredHeight) {
        console.log('Image Crop error: The required dimensions are larger than the target image.');
        return false;
      }

      // And neccessary html
      $(imageTarget).wrap('<div class="ic-container"></div>').before('\
                <div class="ic-overlay-n" id="icOverlayN"></div>\
                <div class="ic-overlay-e" id="icOverlayE"></div>\
                <div class="ic-overlay-s" id="icOverlayS"></div>\
                <div class="ic-overlay-w" id="icOverlayW"></div>\
                <div class="ic-crop-marker" id="icCropMarker">\
                    <div class="ic-resize-handle-nw" id="icResizeHandleNW"></div>\
                    <div class="ic-resize-handle-ne" id="icResizeHandleNE"></div>\
                    <div class="ic-resize-handle-sw" id="icResizeHandleSW"></div>\
                    <div class="ic-resize-handle-se" id="icResizeHandleSE"></div>\
                    <div class="ic-move-handle" id="icMoveHandle"></div>\
                </div>\
            ');
      $cropMarker = $('#icCropMarker');
      $originalImage = $(imageTarget);
      imageScale = origSrc.width / $originalImage.width();
      imageRatio = origSrc.width / origSrc.height;
      cropRatio = requiredWidth / requiredHeight;
      adjustedRequiredWidth = requiredWidth / imageScale;
      adjustedRequiredHeight = requiredHeight / imageScale;

      centerCropMarker();
      repositionOverlay();

      $cropMarker.on('mousedown touchstart', startResize);
      $cropMarker.on('mousedown touchstart', '#icMoveHandle', startMoving);
      imageLoaded.resolve();
    };
    origSrc.src = imageTarget.src;
  };

  function startResize(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    saveEventState(e);
    $doc.on('mousemove touchmove', resizing);
    $doc.on('mouseup touchend', endResize);
  };

  function endResize(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $doc.off('mouseup touchend', endResize);
    $doc.off('mousemove touchmove', resizing);
  };

  function resizing(e) {
    var mouse = {},
      width,
      height,
      left,
      top,
      originalWidth = $cropMarker.outerWidth(),
      originalHeight = $cropMarker.outerHeight(),
      originalOffset = $cropMarker.position();
    mouse.x = (e.clientX || e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX) + $(window).scrollLeft();
    mouse.y = (e.clientY || e.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY) + $(window).scrollTop();

    var SE = false,
      SW = false,
      NW = false,
      NE = false;

    if ($(eventState.evnt.target).is('#icResizeHandleSE')) {
      SE = true;
    } else if ($(eventState.evnt.target).is('#icResizeHandleSW')) {
      SW = true;
    } else if ($(eventState.evnt.target).is('#icResizeHandleNW')) {
      NW = true;
    } else if ($(eventState.evnt.target).is('#icResizeHandleNE')) {
      NE = true;
    }

    if (SE) {
      width = mouse.x - eventState.containerLeft - $originalImage.offset().left;
      height = width / requiredWidth * requiredHeight;
      left = eventState.containerLeft;
      top = eventState.containerTop;
    } else if (SW) {
      width = eventState.containerWidth - (mouse.x - eventState.containerLeft - $originalImage.offset().left);
      height = width / requiredWidth * requiredHeight;
      left = mouse.x - $originalImage.offset().left;
      top = eventState.containerTop;
    } else if (NW) {
      width = eventState.containerWidth - (mouse.x - eventState.containerLeft - $originalImage.offset().left);
      height = width / requiredWidth * requiredHeight;
      left = mouse.x - $originalImage.offset().left;
      top = originalOffset.top + originalHeight - height;
    } else if (NE) {
      width = mouse.x - eventState.containerLeft - $originalImage.offset().left;
      height = width / requiredWidth * requiredHeight;
      left = eventState.containerLeft;
      top = originalOffset.top + originalHeight - height;
    }

    if (
      top >= 0 &&
      left >= 0 &&
      Math.round(top + height) <= Math.round($originalImage.height()) &&
      Math.round(left + width) <= Math.round($originalImage.width())
    ) {
      allowResize = true;
    }

    if (allowResize) {
      // Over top boundary
      if (top < 0) {
        height = originalHeight + originalOffset.top;
        width = height / requiredHeight * requiredWidth;
        top = 0;
        if (NW) {
          left = originalOffset.left - (width - originalWidth);
        }
        allowResize = false;
      }
      // Over left boundary
      else if (left < 0) {
        width = originalWidth + originalOffset.left;
        height = width / requiredWidth * requiredHeight;
        left = 0;
        if (SE) {
          top = originalOffset.top - (height - originalHeight);
        }
        allowResize = false;
      }
      // Over bottom boundary
      else if (Math.round(top + height) > Math.round($originalImage.height())) {
        height = $originalImage.height() - top;
        width = height / requiredHeight * requiredWidth;
        if (SW) {
          left = originalOffset.left - (width - originalWidth);
        }
        allowResize = false;
      }
      // Over right boundary
      else if (Math.round(left + width) > Math.round($originalImage.width())) {
        width = $originalImage.width() - left;
        height = width / requiredWidth * requiredHeight;
        if (NE) {
          top = originalOffset.top - (height - originalHeight);
        }
        allowResize = false;
      }

      // Check for min width / height
      if (width > adjustedRequiredWidth && height > adjustedRequiredHeight) {
        $cropMarker.outerWidth(width).outerHeight(height);
        $cropMarker.css({
          'left': left,
          'top': top
        });
      } else {
        if (SW || NW) {
          left = left - (adjustedRequiredWidth - width);
        }
        if (NW || NE) {
          top = top - (adjustedRequiredHeight - height);
        }
        $cropMarker.outerWidth(adjustedRequiredWidth).outerHeight(adjustedRequiredHeight);
        $cropMarker.css({
          'left': left,
          'top': top
        });
      }
    }
    repositionOverlay();
  }

  function startMoving(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    saveEventState(e);
    $doc.on('mousemove touchmove', moving);
    $doc.on('mouseup touchend', endMoving);
  };

  function endMoving(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $doc.off('mouseup touchend', endMoving);
    $doc.off('mousemove touchmove', moving);
  };

  function moving(e) {
    var top,
      left,
      mouse = {},
      touches;
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    touches = e.originalEvent.touches;

    mouse.x = (e.clientX || e.pageX || touches[0].clientX) + $(window).scrollLeft();
    mouse.y = (e.clientY || e.pageY || touches[0].clientY) + $(window).scrollTop();

    top = mouse.y - (eventState.mouseY - eventState.containerTop);
    left = mouse.x - (eventState.mouseX - eventState.containerLeft);
    if (top < 0) {
      top = 0;
    }
    if (top + $cropMarker.outerHeight() > $originalImage.height()) {
      top = $originalImage.height() - $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
    }
    if (left < 0) {
      left = 0;
    }
    if (left + $cropMarker.outerWidth() > $originalImage.width()) {
      left = $originalImage.width() - $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    }
    $cropMarker.css({
      'top': top,
      'left': left
    });
    repositionOverlay();
  };

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    var top,
      left,
      shiftAmount,
      top = $cropMarker.position().top,
      left = $cropMarker.position().left;
    if (e.shiftKey) {
      shiftAmount = 10;
    } else {
      shiftAmount = 1;
    }

    if (e.keyCode === 37) {
      left = left - shiftAmount;
    } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
      top = top - shiftAmount;
    } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
      left = left + shiftAmount;
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
      top = top + shiftAmount;
    }

    if (top < 0) {
      top = 0;
    }
    if (top + $cropMarker.outerHeight() > $originalImage.height()) {
      top = $originalImage.height() - $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    }
    if (left < 0) {
      left = 0;
    }
    if (left + $cropMarker.outerWidth() > $originalImage.width()) {
      left = $originalImage.width() - $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
    }

    if (keyboardMove) {
      $cropMarker.css({
        'top': top,
        'left': left
      });
      repositionOverlay();
    }
  });

  $doc.click(function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('.ic-container').length) {
      keyboardMove = true;
    } else {
      keyboardMove = false;
    }
  })

  var saveEventState = function(e) {
    eventState.containerWidth = $cropMarker.outerWidth();
    eventState.containerHeight = $cropMarker.outerHeight();
    eventState.containerLeft = $cropMarker.position().left;
    eventState.containerTop = $cropMarker.position().top;
    eventState.mouseX = (e.clientX || e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX) + $(window).scrollLeft();
    eventState.mouseY = (e.clientY || e.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY) + $(window).scrollTop();
    eventState.evnt = e;
  };

  var centerCropMarker = function() {
    if (cropRatio > imageRatio) {
      $cropMarker.outerWidth($originalImage.width());
      $cropMarker.outerHeight($cropMarker.outerWidth() / requiredWidth * requiredHeight);
      $cropMarker.css({
        top: ($originalImage.height() - $cropMarker.height()) / 2 + 'px',
        left: 0
      });
    } else {
      $cropMarker.outerHeight($originalImage.height());
      $cropMarker.outerWidth($cropMarker.outerHeight() / requiredHeight * requiredWidth);
      $cropMarker.css({
        left: ($originalImage.width() - $cropMarker.width()) / 2 + 'px',
        top: 0
      });
    }
  }

  function repositionOverlay() {
    var imgWidth = $originalImage[0].getBoundingClientRect().width,
      imgHeight = $originalImage[0].getBoundingClientRect().height,
      cropTop = $cropMarker.position().top,
      cropLeft = $cropMarker.position().left,
      cropWidth = $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().width,
      cropHeight = $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().height,
      cropBorder = parseFloat($cropMarker.css('border-top-width'));
    $('#icOverlayN').css({
      right: imgWidth - cropLeft - cropWidth,
      height: cropTop,
      left: cropLeft
    });
    $('#icOverlayE').css({
      left: cropLeft + cropWidth
    });
    $('#icOverlayS').css({
      right: imgWidth - cropLeft - cropWidth,
      top: cropTop + cropHeight,
      left: cropLeft
    });
    $('#icOverlayW').css({
      width: cropLeft
    });
  };

  // Crop to required size
  this.crop = function() {
    var cropCanvas,
      img = new Image(),
      scale = origSrc.width / $originalImage.width(),
      left = Math.round($cropMarker.position().left * scale),
      top = Math.round($cropMarker.position().top * scale),
      width = Math.round($cropMarker.outerWidth() * scale),
      height = Math.round($cropMarker.outerHeight() * scale);
    results;

    cropCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    cropCanvas.width = requiredWidth;
    cropCanvas.height = requiredHeight;
    cropCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(origSrc, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, requiredWidth, requiredHeight);

    img.src = cropCanvas.toDataURL();

    var results = {
      img: img,
      left: left,
      top: top,
      width: width,
      height: height,
      requiredWidth: requiredWidth,
      requiredHeight: requiredHeight
    };
    return results;
  }

  this.position = function(left, top, width, height) {
    $.when(imageLoaded).done(function() {
      var scale = origSrc.width / $originalImage.width();
      left = Math.round(left / scale),
        top = Math.round(top / scale),
        width = Math.round(width / scale),
        height = Math.round(height / scale);
      $cropMarker.outerWidth(width).outerHeight(height);
      $cropMarker.css({
        'left': left,
        'top': top
      });
      repositionOverlay();
    });
  }

  this.cropReset = function() {
    centerCropMarker();
    repositionOverlay();
  }

  // Viewport resize
  $(window).resize(function() {
    imageScale = origSrc.width / $originalImage.width();
    adjustedRequiredWidth = requiredWidth / imageScale;
    adjustedRequiredHeight = requiredHeight / imageScale;
    centerCropMarker();
    repositionOverlay();
  });

  init();
};

// Initiate Image Crop
if ($('#exampleImage').length) {
  var exampleCrop = new imageCrop('#exampleImage', 200, 200);
}

// Crop event
$('#exampleCrop').on('click', function() {
  var results = exampleCrop.crop();
  $('body').html(results.img);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

section {
  height: 100%;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.drop {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Lobster, Arial, serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-properties: border;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.image-resize {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.btn .fa:first-child {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

// Layout CSS
.layout {
  height: 100%;
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
  }
  .btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    z-index: 999;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  }
}

// Image Crop CSS
.ic-container {
  position: relative;
}

.ic-overlay-n,
.ic-overlay-e,
.ic-overlay-s,
.ic-overlay-w {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.ic-overlay-n {
  top: 0;
}

.ic-overlay-e {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.ic-overlay-s {
  bottom: 0;
}

.ic-overlay-w {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.ic-resize-handle-ne,
.ic-resize-handle-se,
.ic-resize-handle-nw,
.ic-resize-handle-sw {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #c92437;
  z-index: 999;
}

.ic-resize-handle-nw {
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: nw-resize;
}

.ic-resize-handle-sw {
  bottom: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  cursor: sw-resize;
}

.ic-resize-handle-ne {
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  cursor: ne-resize;
}

.ic-resize-handle-se {
  bottom: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  cursor: se-resize;
}

.ic-crop-marker {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  border: solid 2px rgba(201, 36, 55, .5);
  cursor: move;
}

.ic-move-handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.ic-container img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Upload image -->
<section id="sectionDragAndDrop">
  <div class="drop" id="drop">
    <p>Drag & drop or click here to upload an image.</p>
  </div>
  <input class="file-upload hidden" id="fileUpload" type="file">
</section>

<!-- Resize image -->
<section class="hidden" id="sectionResize">
  <div class="image-resize" id="imageResize"></div>
  <button class="btn" id="crop"><span class='fa fa-crop'></span> Submit</button>
</section>

<!-- Insert thumbnail -->
<section class="hidden" id="sectionThumbnail">
  <div class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail"></div>
</section>
```

This will work here but if the browser height is more than "submit" button is covered up by an overlay and we can't click on it..

Check the fiddle example-
[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/rxv6dnkz/1/)

Comment: #crop{
  z-index:10;
  cursor:pointer;
}

Comment: It's still not working :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the button out of the resize `section` where the image is being added. You then need to edit your javascript wherever you see the `hidden` class being toggled on `#sectionResize` to include the same code on `#crop`. See below or in this updated [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/w62hacqb/) Hope it helps!

```js
$('#drop').on('click', function() {
    $('#fileUpload').trigger('click');
});

$('#fileUpload').on('change', function(e) {
    addImage(e.target);
});

$("#drop").on("dragover", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass('dragging');
});

$("#drop").on("dragleave", function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass('dragging');
});

$("#drop").on("drop", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    var data = e.dataTransfer || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    addImage(data);
});

function addImage(data) {
    var file = data.files[0];
    if (file.type.indexOf('image') === -1) {
        alert('Sorry, the file you uploaded doesn\'t appear to be an image.');
        return false;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            if (img.width < 200 || img.height < 200) {
                alert('Sorry, the image you uploaded doesn\'t appear to be large enough.');
                return false;
            }
            cropImage(img);
        }
        img.src = event.target.result;
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function cropImage(originalImage) {

    $(originalImage).attr('id', 'fullImage');
    $('#imageResize').html(originalImage);
    $('#sectionDragAndDrop').addClass('hidden');
    $('#sectionResize').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#crop').removeClass('hidden');

    var newImage = new imageCrop('#fullImage', 200, 200);

    $('#crop').on('click', function() {
        var results = newImage.crop();
        $('#thumbnail').html(results.img);
        $('#sectionResize').addClass('hidden');
        $('#crop').addClass('hidden');
        $('#sectionThumbnail').removeClass('hidden');
    });

}




// Requires jQuery
var imageCrop = function(imageTarget, requiredWidth, requiredHeight) {
    // Variables
    var $doc = $(document),
        $cropMarker,
        $originalImage,
        origSrc = new Image(),
        imageTarget = $(imageTarget).get(0),
        imageScale,
        imageRatio,
        cropRatio,
        adjustedRequiredWidth,
        adjustedRequiredHeight,
        eventState = {},
        allowResize = true,
        keyboardMove = false,
        imageLoaded = new $.Deferred();

    origSrc.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

    function init() {
        origSrc.onload = function() {
            // Check to make sure the target image is large enough
            if (origSrc.width < requiredWidth || origSrc.height < requiredHeight) {
                console.log('Image Crop error: The required dimensions are larger than the target image.');
                return false;
            }

            // And neccessary html
            $(imageTarget).wrap('<div class="ic-container"></div>').before('\
                <div class="ic-overlay-n" id="icOverlayN"></div>\
                <div class="ic-overlay-e" id="icOverlayE"></div>\
                <div class="ic-overlay-s" id="icOverlayS"></div>\
                <div class="ic-overlay-w" id="icOverlayW"></div>\
                <div class="ic-crop-marker" id="icCropMarker">\
                    <div class="ic-resize-handle-nw" id="icResizeHandleNW"></div>\
                    <div class="ic-resize-handle-ne" id="icResizeHandleNE"></div>\
                    <div class="ic-resize-handle-sw" id="icResizeHandleSW"></div>\
                    <div class="ic-resize-handle-se" id="icResizeHandleSE"></div>\
                    <div class="ic-move-handle" id="icMoveHandle"></div>\
                </div>\
            ');
            $cropMarker = $('#icCropMarker');
            $originalImage = $(imageTarget);
            imageScale = origSrc.width / $originalImage.width();
            imageRatio = origSrc.width / origSrc.height;
            cropRatio = requiredWidth / requiredHeight;
            adjustedRequiredWidth = requiredWidth / imageScale;
            adjustedRequiredHeight = requiredHeight / imageScale;

            centerCropMarker();
            repositionOverlay();

            $cropMarker.on('mousedown touchstart', startResize);
            $cropMarker.on('mousedown touchstart', '#icMoveHandle', startMoving);
            imageLoaded.resolve();
        };
        origSrc.src = imageTarget.src;
    };

    function startResize(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        saveEventState(e);
        $doc.on('mousemove touchmove', resizing);
        $doc.on('mouseup touchend', endResize);
    };

    function endResize(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $doc.off('mouseup touchend', endResize);
        $doc.off('mousemove touchmove', resizing);
    };

    function resizing(e) {
        var mouse = {},
            width,
            height,
            left,
            top,
            originalWidth = $cropMarker.outerWidth(),
            originalHeight = $cropMarker.outerHeight(),
            originalOffset = $cropMarker.position();
        mouse.x = (e.clientX || e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX) + $(window).scrollLeft();
        mouse.y = (e.clientY || e.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY) + $(window).scrollTop();

        var SE = false,
            SW = false,
            NW = false,
            NE = false;

        if ($(eventState.evnt.target).is('#icResizeHandleSE')) {
            SE = true;
        } else if ($(eventState.evnt.target).is('#icResizeHandleSW')) {
            SW = true;
        } else if ($(eventState.evnt.target).is('#icResizeHandleNW')) {
            NW = true;
        } else if ($(eventState.evnt.target).is('#icResizeHandleNE')) {
            NE = true;
        }

        if (SE) {
            width = mouse.x - eventState.containerLeft - $originalImage.offset().left;
            height = width / requiredWidth * requiredHeight;
            left = eventState.containerLeft;
            top = eventState.containerTop;
        } else if (SW) {
            width = eventState.containerWidth - (mouse.x - eventState.containerLeft - $originalImage.offset().left);
            height = width / requiredWidth * requiredHeight;
            left = mouse.x - $originalImage.offset().left;
            top = eventState.containerTop;
        } else if (NW) {
            width = eventState.containerWidth - (mouse.x - eventState.containerLeft - $originalImage.offset().left);
            height = width / requiredWidth * requiredHeight;
            left = mouse.x - $originalImage.offset().left;
            top = originalOffset.top + originalHeight - height;
        } else if (NE) {
            width = mouse.x - eventState.containerLeft - $originalImage.offset().left;
            height = width / requiredWidth * requiredHeight;
            left = eventState.containerLeft;
            top = originalOffset.top + originalHeight - height;
        }

        if (
            top >= 0 &&
            left >= 0 &&
            Math.round(top + height) <= Math.round($originalImage.height()) &&
            Math.round(left + width) <= Math.round($originalImage.width())
        ) {
            allowResize = true;
        }

        if (allowResize) {
            // Over top boundary
            if (top < 0) {
                height = originalHeight + originalOffset.top;
                width = height / requiredHeight * requiredWidth;
                top = 0;
                if (NW) {
                    left = originalOffset.left - (width - originalWidth);
                }
                allowResize = false;
            }
            // Over left boundary
            else if (left < 0) {
                width = originalWidth + originalOffset.left;
                height = width / requiredWidth * requiredHeight;
                left = 0;
                if (SE) {
                    top = originalOffset.top - (height - originalHeight);
                }
                allowResize = false;
            }
            // Over bottom boundary
            else if (Math.round(top + height) > Math.round($originalImage.height())) {
                height = $originalImage.height() - top;
                width = height / requiredHeight * requiredWidth;
                if (SW) {
                    left = originalOffset.left - (width - originalWidth);
                }
                allowResize = false;
            }
            // Over right boundary
            else if (Math.round(left + width) > Math.round($originalImage.width())) {
                width = $originalImage.width() - left;
                height = width / requiredWidth * requiredHeight;
                if (NE) {
                    top = originalOffset.top - (height - originalHeight);
                }
                allowResize = false;
            }

            // Check for min width / height
            if (width > adjustedRequiredWidth && height > adjustedRequiredHeight) {
                $cropMarker.outerWidth(width).outerHeight(height);
                $cropMarker.css({
                    'left': left,
                    'top': top
                });
            } else {
                if (SW || NW) {
                    left = left - (adjustedRequiredWidth - width);
                }
                if (NW || NE) {
                    top = top - (adjustedRequiredHeight - height);
                }
                $cropMarker.outerWidth(adjustedRequiredWidth).outerHeight(adjustedRequiredHeight);
                $cropMarker.css({
                    'left': left,
                    'top': top
                });
            }
        }
        repositionOverlay();
    }

    function startMoving(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        saveEventState(e);
        $doc.on('mousemove touchmove', moving);
        $doc.on('mouseup touchend', endMoving);
    };

    function endMoving(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $doc.off('mouseup touchend', endMoving);
        $doc.off('mousemove touchmove', moving);
    };

    function moving(e) {
        var top,
            left,
            mouse = {},
            touches;
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        touches = e.originalEvent.touches;

        mouse.x = (e.clientX || e.pageX || touches[0].clientX) + $(window).scrollLeft();
        mouse.y = (e.clientY || e.pageY || touches[0].clientY) + $(window).scrollTop();

        top = mouse.y - (eventState.mouseY - eventState.containerTop);
        left = mouse.x - (eventState.mouseX - eventState.containerLeft);
        if (top < 0) {
            top = 0;
        }
        if (top + $cropMarker.outerHeight() > $originalImage.height()) {
            top = $originalImage.height() - $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
        }
        if (left < 0) {
            left = 0;
        }
        if (left + $cropMarker.outerWidth() > $originalImage.width()) {
            left = $originalImage.width() - $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
        }
        $cropMarker.css({
            'top': top,
            'left': left
        });
        repositionOverlay();
    };

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        var top,
            left,
            shiftAmount,
            top = $cropMarker.position().top,
            left = $cropMarker.position().left;
        if (e.shiftKey) {
            shiftAmount = 10;
        } else {
            shiftAmount = 1;
        }

        if (e.keyCode === 37) {
            left = left - shiftAmount;
        } else if (e.keyCode === 38) {
            top = top - shiftAmount;
        } else if (e.keyCode === 39) {
            left = left + shiftAmount;
        } else if (e.keyCode === 40) {
            top = top + shiftAmount;
        }

        if (top < 0) {
            top = 0;
        }
        if (top + $cropMarker.outerHeight() > $originalImage.height()) {
            top = $originalImage.height() - $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
        }
        if (left < 0) {
            left = 0;
        }
        if (left + $cropMarker.outerWidth() > $originalImage.width()) {
            left = $originalImage.width() - $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
        }

        if (keyboardMove) {
            $cropMarker.css({
                'top': top,
                'left': left
            });
            repositionOverlay();
        }
    });

    $doc.click(function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).closest('.ic-container').length) {
            keyboardMove = true;
        } else {
            keyboardMove = false;
        }
    })

    var saveEventState = function(e) {
        eventState.containerWidth = $cropMarker.outerWidth();
        eventState.containerHeight = $cropMarker.outerHeight();
        eventState.containerLeft = $cropMarker.position().left;
        eventState.containerTop = $cropMarker.position().top;
        eventState.mouseX = (e.clientX || e.pageX || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientX) + $(window).scrollLeft();
        eventState.mouseY = (e.clientY || e.pageY || e.originalEvent.touches[0].clientY) + $(window).scrollTop();
        eventState.evnt = e;
    };

    var centerCropMarker = function() {
        if (cropRatio > imageRatio) {
            $cropMarker.outerWidth($originalImage.width());
            $cropMarker.outerHeight($cropMarker.outerWidth() / requiredWidth * requiredHeight);
            $cropMarker.css({
                top: ($originalImage.height() - $cropMarker.height()) / 2 + 'px',
                left: 0
            });
        } else {
            $cropMarker.outerHeight($originalImage.height());
            $cropMarker.outerWidth($cropMarker.outerHeight() / requiredHeight * requiredWidth);
            $cropMarker.css({
                left: ($originalImage.width() - $cropMarker.width()) / 2 + 'px',
                top: 0
            });
        }
    }

    function repositionOverlay() {
        var imgWidth = $originalImage[0].getBoundingClientRect().width,
            imgHeight = $originalImage[0].getBoundingClientRect().height,
            cropTop = $cropMarker.position().top,
            cropLeft = $cropMarker.position().left,
            cropWidth = $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().width,
            cropHeight = $cropMarker[0].getBoundingClientRect().height,
            cropBorder = parseFloat($cropMarker.css('border-top-width'));
        $('#icOverlayN').css({
            right: imgWidth - cropLeft - cropWidth,
            height: cropTop,
            left: cropLeft
        });
        $('#icOverlayE').css({
            left: cropLeft + cropWidth
        });
        $('#icOverlayS').css({
            right: imgWidth - cropLeft - cropWidth,
            top: cropTop + cropHeight,
            left: cropLeft
        });
        $('#icOverlayW').css({
            width: cropLeft
        });
    };

    // Crop to required size
    this.crop = function() {
        var cropCanvas,
            img = new Image(),
            scale = origSrc.width / $originalImage.width(),
            left = Math.round($cropMarker.position().left * scale),
            top = Math.round($cropMarker.position().top * scale),
            width = Math.round($cropMarker.outerWidth() * scale),
            height = Math.round($cropMarker.outerHeight() * scale);
        results;

        cropCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        cropCanvas.width = requiredWidth;
        cropCanvas.height = requiredHeight;
        cropCanvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(origSrc, left, top, width, height, 0, 0, requiredWidth, requiredHeight);

        img.src = cropCanvas.toDataURL();

        var results = {
            img: img,
            left: left,
            top: top,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            requiredWidth: requiredWidth,
            requiredHeight: requiredHeight
        };
        return results;
    }

    this.position = function(left, top, width, height) {
        $.when(imageLoaded).done(function() {
            var scale = origSrc.width / $originalImage.width();
            left = Math.round(left / scale),
                top = Math.round(top / scale),
                width = Math.round(width / scale),
                height = Math.round(height / scale);
            $cropMarker.outerWidth(width).outerHeight(height);
            $cropMarker.css({
                'left': left,
                'top': top
            });
            repositionOverlay();
        });
    }
    
    this.cropReset = function() {
        centerCropMarker();
        repositionOverlay();
    }

    // Viewport resize
    $(window).resize(function() {
        imageScale = origSrc.width / $originalImage.width();
        adjustedRequiredWidth = requiredWidth / imageScale;
        adjustedRequiredHeight = requiredHeight / imageScale;
        centerCropMarker();
        repositionOverlay();
    });

    init();
};

// Initiate Image Crop
if ($('#exampleImage').length) {
    var exampleCrop = new imageCrop('#exampleImage', 200, 200);
}

// Crop event
$('#exampleCrop').on('click', function() {
    var results = exampleCrop.crop();
    $('body').html(results.img);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
section {
  height: 100%;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.drop {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Lobster, Arial, serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-properties: border;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
          transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.image-resize {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
}
.btn {
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 8px 25px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu";
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.btn .fa:first-child {
  margin-right: 5px;
}


.thumbnail {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 5px;
}




// Layout CSS

.layout {
    height: 100%;
    
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
    }

    .btn {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
        bottom: 5px;
        z-index: 999;
        padding: 6px 10px;
        font-family: "Ubuntu";
        font-size: 16px;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    }
}

// Image Crop CSS

.ic-container {
    position: relative;
}

.ic-overlay-n,
.ic-overlay-e,
.ic-overlay-s,
.ic-overlay-w {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.ic-overlay-n {
    top: 0;
}

.ic-overlay-e {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.ic-overlay-s {
    bottom: 0;
}

.ic-overlay-w {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.ic-resize-handle-ne,
.ic-resize-handle-se,
.ic-resize-handle-nw,
.ic-resize-handle-sw {
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background: #c92437;
    z-index: 999;
}

.ic-resize-handle-nw {
    top: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    cursor: nw-resize;
}

.ic-resize-handle-sw {
    bottom: -5px;
    left: -5px;
    cursor: sw-resize;
}

.ic-resize-handle-ne {
    top: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    cursor: ne-resize;
}

.ic-resize-handle-se {
    bottom: -5px;
    right: -5px;
    cursor: se-resize;
}

.ic-crop-marker {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    border: solid 2px rgba(201,36,55,.5);
    cursor: move;
}

.ic-move-handle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.ic-container img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Upload image -->
<section id="sectionDragAndDrop">
    <div class="drop" id="drop">
        <p>Drag & drop or click here to upload an image.</p>
    </div>
    <input class="file-upload hidden" id="fileUpload" type="file">
</section>

<!-- Resize image -->
<section class="hidden" id="sectionResize">
    <div class="image-resize" id="imageResize"></div>
</section>
  <button id="crop" class="btn" id="crop"><span class='fa fa-crop'></span> Submit</button>
<!-- Insert thumbnail -->
<section class="hidden" id="sectionThumbnail">
    <div class="thumbnail" id="thumbnail"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes! Thats working..Thank you soo much :)
Now I'm just having one problem..with submit button still there after cropping

Comment: @nonliving Cool! I'll update my answer to include javascript and html that works fully. Because we took the button out of sectionResize we need to toggle the 'hidden' class on the button. You'll see in my updated answer.

Comment: @nonliving no problem at all. Happy coding!